# R: Replacement has [x] rows, data has [y] - residuals from a linear model in new variable

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable in my data frame called "residuals", which needs to contain the residuals from a linear model. The problem is that R doesn't like it because the output only has 718 rows and the data frame (data.frame.use) has 796. What I would like is for the full 796 cases to be populated with either residuals or an NA. How do I get R to add in the NA? Cheers.

```
data.frame.use$residuals <- resid(lm(FCNA ~ Age + Gender, data = data.frame.use))
```

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, residuals, value = c(-0.310800504671101,  :   replacement has 718 rows, data has 796

```
    Unique_ID Age Gender EFL     O     C     E     A     N     FCPA FCNA FCP FCSC
1        75  19      2   1 2.750 4.000 2.250 4.500 3.250 2.666667  2.0 3.0  3.5
2        77  20      1   1 3.125 3.875 2.375 3.125 3.250 2.333333  1.2 2.0  1.5
3        79  19      1   1 3.500 4.250 4.125 2.125 2.375 2.666667  2.0 2.0  2.0
4        73  20      2   1 2.875 3.500 2.875 4.125 2.250 3.000000  2.4 3.0  2.5
5        76  19      1   1 3.375 4.125 3.625 4.000 2.500 4.000000  3.0 4.0  4.0
6        78  19      1   1 4.125 3.875 4.250 3.250 2.250 4.000000  2.0 3.5  2.0
  FCR
1   3
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   4
```

Comment: Sounds like there are missing observations which were dropped from the model, giving fewer rows than the original. I would use `augment` from the `broom` package to get a data frame with residuals + original observations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I have had a go at using the broom package with the augment command but it doesn't combine the original + residuals. Instead, it removes the cases that are not used in the linear model and simply adds the additional columns. This is better than what I had before but doesn't solve my problem as I still end up with 718 cases.

Comment: Ah yes, augment does that :) In that case, we need some kind of identifier common to the original and the augmented data frames on which we can join. Let me think about it and get back to you. In the meantime, it would help to see some data from `data.frame.use`.

Comment: Hmm, I can think of two possibilities in my data. I do have a "Unique_ID" field in my original (pre-model) data, but the lm function seems to remove it. Otherwise, the augment function does provide a .rownames which we might be able to link back to the original data frame? (The new .rownames column does match to the row number in the original data frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When NA are present, the function `broom::augment` generates a column `.rownames`, which maps to row numbers in the original data frame.

So we can join by adding row numbers to the original data. Note that `.rownames` is of type character, so we have to alter either `.rownames` or the row numbers so as the types match.

Putting all that together, something like this should work. I assume you want standardized residuals `.std.resid`. If not, use `.resid`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

data.frame.use %>% 
  lm(FCNA ~ Age + Gender, data = .) %>% 
  augment() %>% 
  select(.rownames, .std.resid) %>% 
  right_join(mutate(data.frame.use, row = as.character(row_number())), 
             by = c(".rownames" = "row"))
```

Comment: That's seems to be working... if only I knew what it meant! Thanks very much.

Comment: You will work it out in time :) start with the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html).

Comment: How can I add residuals to the original data set if I have different groups and want to estimate the residuals by group? I also have NAs as my linear model has lag predictor values.